# Mac OS X menu bar music player

Tags: macos, applications, menu-bar

Anyone know of a menu bar app that will allow you to pick a song out of your iTunes library and play it, without having to have iTunes running. Alarm Clock allows you to do that (but you need to create an alarm) but it's a great way of just playing the odd song or two. I know there's CloudPlay but I'd of thought there was a free menu bar app out there. There's apps like Ecoute but I just want something that is minimal for playing something when you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this app called [Vox](https://coppertino.com/vox/mac). I was looking for something similar to yourself and it seems to be the best option that I can find.

Here is an image of some of the UI (from their website, linked above):

[image: Vox]
<sub>(source: [coppertino.com](https://coppertino.com/themes/vox/assets/extreme-new/img/vox-mac-play.jpg))</sub>

When the app is running, you also get menu bar icons like these: [image: Vox Menubar]

The lefthand button shows a dropdown with the 6 next songs and has a shortcut to open the full app again:

[image: Vox Menubar 2]

A couple of points to note:

- I've found that if you have playlists organised into playlist folders in iTunes, that unfortunately it won't recognise them all.
- You have to reload your music from iTunes every time you open the app.

I know this is a late answer, but hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

**beardedspice**

is a menu bar player which is mapped on the media keys of your keyboard or any keys you like.

it controls

- iTunes
- Spotify
- Vox
- VLC
- and many webbased players like youtube, vimeo, etc.

You can get it from
https://beardedspice.github.io

or if you have brew installed, you can type

`brew cask install beardedspice`

in the Terminal App.